# Cannot login into iAd Network?

Tags: ios, iad

So I've agreed to the iAd contract and it's been about 2 1/2 weeks now since I've agreed to it, but when I go to the iAd network to login, it says that my Apple ID and password is wrong but it clearly isn't because I'm using that Apple ID and password to login into iTunes Connect. So why is it locking me out of iAd Network?

Comment: Try contacting Apple https://developer.apple.com/contact/

Comment: I currently have the same issue. However it does not tell me the password is wrong, it begins to load, then goes back to the login screen with no error or wrong password message. Nothing.